# How to get specific range value from numpy.random.rand()?

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way to get the specific range of array from the results of `numpy.random.rand()`?

Here is sample code: To create a random matrix of 4 rows and 19 columns-

```
import numpy as np

random_matrix_1 = np.random.rand(4,19)
```

above code will generate random numbers. Can we generate all the numbers within a specific range like 19.00 to 27.00?

Comment: Since you need of interval=8 (27 - 19), then multply result array by 8 and add 19

Comment: From the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.random_sample.html#numpy.random.random_sample) `(27 - 19) * np.random.random_sample((4, 19)) + 19`

Comment: You can refer to this post for further reference: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/281162/scale-a-number-between-a-range

Comment: Thanks to all. The code is working fine.

Answer (score 4):

I think it would be fine to just use array broadcasting in this case, you could 1-line it with:

```py
mat = (np.random.rand(shapex, shapey) * (rmax - rmin)) + rmin
```

I'm not aware of any built-in function you could use for this purpose.